# Exception System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException - Backgroundworker

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read files which were opened by the openFileDialog into a richTextBox (called websiteInput_rtxt) using a backgroundworker(bgFileOpener).

```
   private void bgFileOpener_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
            {
                using (StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(file))
                {

                    // while the stream reader didn't reach the end of the file - read the next line and report it
                    while (!sreader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        if (bgFileOpener.CancellationPending)
                        {
                            e.Cancel = true;
                            return;
                        }

                        bgFileOpener.ReportProgress(0, sreader.ReadLine() + "\n");
                        Thread.Sleep(15);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

    }

    private void bgFileOpener_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            websiteInput_rtxt.AppendText(e.UserState.ToString());
    }
```

**When the form is closed while the bgWorker is still running an exception is thrown which doesn't seem to be caught**,
can someone tell me what is missing or what could cause the exception?

Exception message is called "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" and the innerException says something about the RichTextBox.

Comment: What is the exact inner exception? Is `websiteInput_rtxt.AppendText(e.UserState.ToString());` running on the worker thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Closing the form doesn't immediately stop the background worker, which means your `ProgressChanged` event can still be raised on the form after it's been closed.

You can work around this via:

```
private void bgFileOpener_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsDisposed) // Don't do this if we've been closed already
    {
        // Kill the bg work:
        bgFileOpener.CancelAsync();
    }
    else
        websiteInput_rtxt.AppendText(e.UserState.ToString());
}
```